# Ubuntu Crontab Edit

Tags: shell, ubuntu, terminal, cron

My issue.

I need to remove session files that are stored on the server in the /tmp folder older than 2 days.

I've added this in crontab in terminal.

```
#!/bin/bash
find /tmp/sess_* -mtime +2 -exec rm {} \;
```

I save it out but keep getting bad minute error, can anyone help and let me know where I am going wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`crontab` does not accept a shebang (<s>and the shebang is wrong anyway</s> that's obviously just a Markdown problem which has been fixed). Try, for instance,

```
SHELL=/bin/bash

* * * * * find /tmp/sess_* -mtime +2 -exec rm {} \;
```

if you want to run the job every minute. See `man 5 crontab` for details.

---

Update:

**Q:** What does the `* * * * *` in the minimal crontab above mean?

**A:** Those five fields are date and time fields controlling when the job is executed.

According to [`man 5 crontab`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man5/crontab.5.html),

> The time and date fields are:
>
> ```
>          field          allowed values
>          -----          --------------
>          minute         0-59
>          hour           0-23
>          day of month   1-31
>          month          1-12 (or names, see below)
>          day of week    0-7 (0 or 7 is Sun, or use names)
> ```

So, here are some examples:

- `* * * * *`: every minute;
- `00 * * * *`: the beginning of every hour;
- `00 03 * * *`: 3 a.m. every day;
- `00 03 01 * *`: 3 a.m. on the first day of every month;
- `00 23 * * 0`: 11 p.m. every Sunday;
- `00 23 * * Sun`: same as above;
- `*/15 * * * *`: every fifteen minutes.

You can get more examples and explanations by Googling things like "vixie cron tutorial".

Comment: yep, ok. Thanks. What is a shebang? sorry not added this before.

Comment: @user2191937 Shebangs are things like the `#!/bin/bash` you originally had. `crontab` doesn't need a shebang (but it won't hurt since it's simply dismissed as a comment). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix).

Comment: Thank you! One tiny more thing the * * * * * what do they do and do I need them in this instance?

Cheers!

Comment: @user2191937 That's definitely not a tiny thing! That's how `cron` schedule jobs — what `cron` is all about. See the updated explanation and examples. Make sure to read `man 5 crontab` (also `man 1 crontab` and `man 8 cron`).

Comment: @user2191937: "*What is a shebang?*" -- Get into the habit of using Google (or some other search engine) and/or Wikipedia. It would have answered your question more quickly, and in greater detail, than posting a comment here.